# problem with css showing the divisions of the page

Tags: php, html, css

This is most likely the culprit for this page:
http://www.mypicx.com/04192010/ff/

```
table
{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
table,th, td
{
border: 1px solid black;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size:3;
font-size:10px;


}
th
{
background-color:#A7C942;
color:white;
}
```

I don't know why, but the page has some php scripts in it which shows a table from mysql database. As you can see in the url above.
Please help, why do I see those lines everytime I put those css scripts

Comment: we kind of need to see the markup... Are you using a table based layout? IT seems like maybe you are and your `border: 1px solid black;
` is getting applied to all the tables instead of jsut the ones you want it to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your borders are being set to all of the tables in the page, and not just one.

Try something like:

```
.mytable
{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
.mytable th, .mytable td
{
border: 1px solid black;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size:3;
font-size:10px;


}
.mytable th
{
background-color:#A7C942;
color:white;
}
```

And use a class in the HTML on the table you wish to have these borders on:

```
 <table class="mytable">
    <tr>
         <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td><span class="A">8:00 AM</span></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: Don't you mean `.mytable th, .mytable td` ?